# Display fields from Pagelayout in VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, metadata-api

Requirement is like, we need to create a VF Page which should display all the fields from Account - Account Layout. So in future if any field is added to this page layout should reflect the same in the VF Page.

For getting the fields of that page layout, we used Metadata API

```
List<String> lstFieldsAPI = new List<String>();
List<Metadata.Metadata> layouts = 
    Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, 
                                 new List<String> {'Account-Account Layout'});
Metadata.Layout layoutMd = (Metadata.Layout) layouts.get(0);

for (Metadata.LayoutSection section : layoutMd.layoutSections) {
    for (Metadata.LayoutColumn column : section.layoutColumns) {
        if (column.layoutItems != null) {
            for (Metadata.LayoutItem item : column.layoutItems) {
                System.debug(item.field);
                lstFieldsAPI.add(item.field);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This "lstFieldsAPI" holds all the fields that are available in that page layout at a given time.

Now while building the VF Page, without knowing which fields are available how can we build a page block section or how to iterate the fields in a page block table? Even for a apex:repeat we need to know the api so that we can iterate it through and display the table.

Please advise.

Comment: For this use case, UI API makes more sense, it gives details on metadata and data in a single response. Have you explored it?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started.htm

Comment: i'd look hard at the apex:detail component rather than trying to reproduce all this logic